# java.lang.OutofMemoryError - GC overhead limit exceeded - Spring batch - JdbcTemplate - BatchPreparedStatementSetter

Tags: garbage-collection, out-of-memory, spring-batch, jdbctemplate

Our application batch designed with spring batch. One of the job designed to read an input text file and writes into database. The file size is usually huge(mostly more than 500MB).

So here the problem is when job trying to write into database using jdbcTemplate it gives an java.lang.OutofMemoryError - GC overhead limit exceeded error.

I can understand at what point this error would occur but i am unable to relate that to the problem i am facing.

i am using below template to write into database.

the job currently run with this JVM parameters - Xms512M -Xmx8192M

```
 jdbcTemplate.batchUpdates(qryString,new BatchPreparedStatementSetter(){

    public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps,int 1) throws SQLException{

    //Get object from list
    //Set values to ps

    }

    public int getBatchSize(){
      //return batchsize
    }
  });
```

Can someone helpme to find out what causing the problem.

Comment: You should profile your application and see what objects are taking up so much memory. I like using Java Mission Control for this (see http://java-performance.info/oracle-java-mission-control-overview/ for a guide on how to use it).

Comment: If the input file size is 500 MB, then I suggest you to follow partitioned step way. Can you post the code for your job?